# Redshift - Lock not preventing serializable error with Lambdas in parallel

Tags: sql, python-3.x, database, aws-lambda, amazon-redshift

**Background:**

I have around 10-15 sources that I pull data from.
And I have a AWS Lambda that runs once for each *source* every 3 minutes.

The main idea for this Lambda is to update Redshift with real-time data.
Each iteration will retrieve around 10-50 thousand rows combined of existing *updated data* and *new data* from the given source.

The Lambda will do the following in python3.7:

- Fetch data
- Clean data
- Build query for redshift

I am currently using an *upsert* procedure derived from [Redshift's Documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/merge-specify-a-column-list.html)
The reason for this is that all the rows are unique and the unique rows are being constantly updated on the source.

The final procedure looks like this:

```
begin read write;

lock table_name;

create temp table stage (like table_name);

INSERT INTO stage(unique_id, name) VALUES (1232, $$Hello World$$), (1214, $$Foo Bar$$);

update table_name set name = stage.name from stage where table_name.unique_id = stage.unique_id;

delete from stage using table_name where table_name.unique_id = stage.unique_id; 

insert into table_name(unique_id, name) select unique_id, name from stage;

end transaction;

drop table stage;
```

**Issue**

The upsert works just fine, the problem is, since I am running it in parallel across multiple sources I always *spontaneously* end up with Serializable Errors as such:

```
DETAIL:  Serializable isolation violation on table - 202410, transactions forming the cycle are: 5563332, 5563333 (pid:23375)
```

There can be two reasons for this.

- Two sources are trying to excecute at the same time
- One source had an overhead of over 3 minutes and then overlapped withthe next
  iteration

By reading the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_LOCK.html) it seems like using a 'lock' at the beginning of the procedure would prevent errors.
But so far it hasn't worked at all and I keep getting errors.. Any ideas?